# Active Directory notifications

Tags: c++, active-directory

I have seen this example documented by microsoft, but cannot get it to work in visual studio 2012, under a console project.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676877(v=vs.85).aspx

Is there something I am missing, ie. is a console application correct.

The Errors I get are:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ldap_openW referenced in function "int __cdecl GetChangeNotifications(wchar_t *)" (?GetChangeNotifications@@YAHPA_W@Z) C:\projects\AD_Notifications\AD_Change_Notifications\AD_Change_Notifications\AD_Change_Notifications.obj    AD_Change_Notifications
```

From what I have been reading its a linker error, which is kinda obvious, but it is all in 1 file, so I don't understand what I am suppose to be linking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I found in java is quoted below from https://community.oracle.com/thread/1158217

```
/**
 * ldapnotify.java
 * December 2004
 * Sample JNDI application that uses AD LDAP Notification Control.
 * 
 **/

import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.naming.ldap.*;
import com.sun.jndi.ldap.ctl.*;
import javax.naming.directory.*;

class NotifyControl implements Control {
     public byte[] getEncodedValue() {
             return new byte[] {};
     }
       public String getID() {
          return "1.2.840.113556.1.4.528";
     }
      public boolean isCritical() {
          return true;
     }
}

class ldapnotify {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

          Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
          String adminName = "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=antipodes,DC=com";
          String adminPassword = "XXXXXXXX";
          String ldapURL = "ldap://mydc.antipodes.com:389";
          String searchBase = "DC=antipodes,DC=com";

          //For persistent search can only use objectClass=*
          String searchFilter = "(objectClass=*)";

               env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");

          //set security credentials, note using simple cleartext authentication
          env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION,"simple");
          env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,adminName);
          env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,adminPassword);

          //connect to my domain controller
          env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,ldapURL);

          try {
               //bind to the domain controller
                  LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env,null);

               // Create the search controls           
               SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();

               //Specify the attributes to return
               String returnedAtts[] = null;
               searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);

               //Specify the search scope
               searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

                     //Specifiy the search time limit, in this case unlimited
               searchCtls.setTimeLimit(0);

               //Request the LDAP Persistent Search control
                     Control[] rqstCtls = new Control[]{new NotifyControl()};
                     ctx.setRequestControls(rqstCtls);

               //Now perform the search
               NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search(searchBase,searchFilter,searchCtls);
                SearchResult sr;
                     Attributes attrs;

               //Continue waiting for changes....forever
               while(true) {
                    System.out.println("Waiting for changes..., press Ctrl C to exit");

                     sr = (SearchResult)answer.next();
                          System.out.println(">>>" + sr.getName());

                    //Print out the modified attributes
                    //instanceType and objectGUID are always returned
                    attrs = sr.getAttributes();
                    if (attrs != null) {
                         try {

                              for (NamingEnumeration ae = attrs.getAll();ae.hasMore();) {
                                   Attribute attr = (Attribute)ae.next();
                                   System.out.println("Attribute: " + attr.getID());
                                   for (NamingEnumeration e = attr.getAll();e.hasMore();System.out.println("   " + e.next().toString()));
                              }
                         } 
                         catch (NullPointerException e)     {
                              System.err.println("Problem listing attributes: " + e);
                         }
                    }
               }
              } 

          catch (NamingException e) {
                      System.err.println("LDAP Notifications failure. " + e);
              } 
       } 
}
```